# Does working 2 jobs in a company count as an experience?

Tags: work-experience, job-description

I work at Top Tier Hosting Company Tree that handles variety of hosting companies.

Originally I signed up for Hosting Company Tree “Brand1” account as a specialist.

My total work in Hosting Company Tree is 2years

During my time I am working with the assigned account which is Brand1 customers/clients doing technical stuff within my 2 years term.

Now at the lateral part of my job at Brand1 I got upskilled to work with Brand2 clients/customers too total of 8 months within the 2 years term.

Sample dates

```
Brand1 January 2022 - January 2024 (2 years)
Brand2 May 2023 - January 2024 (8 months)
```

They have different tools and knowledge of content so I undergo training of Brand2 as well.

During my time with Brand2 May 2023 - January 2024 i am also working with Brand1 customers/ clients

Now my question is should i add it as experience
2 years for Brand 1 and 8 months for brand 2, total of 32 months working with Hosting Company Tree? Or just 2 years(24 months)

Comment: If you want to remove details from the edit history, I believe you can ask the moderators to do that for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The duration of the **work experience** is the total time of employment - 2 years. This has nothing to do with the count of projects, accounts or customers you might have worked with during that period.

The technical experience, or domain knowledge, or skills acquired during the work tenure includes whatever tools, technology, domain you have worked with, and similar or different roles you played during the employment.

Answer (score 32):

It's just two years' experience.

You didn't work two jobs, you worked in two business units. Even though it can feel like working two jobs *especially* when the business units are so siloed that they are pretty much separate entities - it's still just a separate business unit.

And this is something specific to your *specific* scenario that I can personally attest to.

Comment: "And this is something specific to your specific scenario that I can personally attest to." Um, is that the yikes I think it is? lol

Comment: @yshavit - Not Yikes at all - more like happy coincidence :)

Comment: That is one way to learn not to post any kind of identifiable information, including company information. Haha.

Comment: @MagnieMozios - hence why I only said, I can personally attest to their *specific* situation :)

Answer (score 3):

What you haven't said is what you're counting years for. Depending on that, the answer could sit anywhere on the scale from "Absolutely not" to "No, but also kind of yes."

For example, if you're thinking about some point of employment law which depends on how many years you've been at the company, it's at the "Absolutely not" end of the scale. A year is a year, no matter how industrious you've been.

At the "kind of" end of the scale, if you're applying for a job and it wants 3 years of experience, it may be relevant. There's a saying that some people's idea of 10 years of experience is 1 year of experience 10 times, and time requirement in a job ad is often more wish than demand anyway. So if you have credible reason to believe that you've made exceptionally good use of your 2 years, by all means take a punt on the application. Still don't claim in your CV that you have more experience than the calendar allows (which is a great way to get your application binned immediately) but lean on all the relevant stuff you've learned in interviews and/or cover letters.